# Unable to perform conditional rendering in react responive carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I am looping through an array in React and conditionally returning inside of carousel component.

Code:

```
  projects.map((proj) => {
   if(proj.active){
      return (
        <Carousel emulateTouch swipeable useKeyboardArrows infiniteLoop>
          <ProjectItemMob singleProject={proj} />
        </Carousel>
      );
   }
  })
```

This gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Any fixes? It works without the condition, but I need to add the condition.

EDIT:

First, filter the array according to the condition and update the state.

```
 const [allEnabledProjects, setallEnabledProjects] = React.useState([]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
   if (projects) {
     let enabledProjects = projects.filter(
       (proj) => proj.isActive === true
    );
     if (enabledProjects.length > 0) {
       setallEnabledProjects(enabledProjects);
     } else {
       setallEnabledProjects([]);
     }
   }
 }, [projects]);
```

After that, use the filtered array to map so that we don't have to put the condition inside the Carousel Component.

```
 allEnabledProjects.map((proj) => {
    return (
      <Carousel emulateTouch swipeable useKeyboardArrows infiniteLoop>
        <ProjectItemMob singleProject={proj} />
      </Carousel>
    );
 })
```

Although I'm able to use a different approach and it is working but still I'm not able to figure out why conditioning inside the Carousel Component is throwing that error.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you need to filter out the `undefined` after you do this mapping? So maybe `projects.map(proj => { ... }).filter(el => el)`?

Comment: My guess is for some `proj`, you don't have `active` key, that caused `type null` error.

Comment: There are 2 objects inside the projects array and both have the active keys. So that is not the case.  I tried what @Nick suggested in a different way. I filtered the projects that have active === true into a new array, and then mapped in that filtered array. That worked.